# WPF Datagrid single click row to open new Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, click

My first post here! And new to coding!...

I have a WPF Datagrid in a Frame on a Page. I would like to click (preferably single click) on a row and use the ID value stored in one of the columns to Navigate to (open) a new Page.

Using MouseDoubleClick sometimes I can double click row to open a Page. But sometimes it is throwing:
"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in program.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

on line (see code behind below for complete method):

```
string ID = ((DataRowView)PersonDataGrid.SelectedItem).Row["PersonID"].ToString();
```

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="PersonDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
     SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit ="FullRow"      
     MouseDoubleClick="PersonDataGrid_CellClicked"  >
  <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PersonID}" 
          ClipboardContentBinding="{x:Null}" Header="ID"  />
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource myDataGridCellStyle}">
           <EventSetter Event="DataGridCell.MouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="PersonDataGrid_CellClicked"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Code Behind:

```
private void PersonDataGrid_CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)

    {
        string ID = ((DataRowView)PersonDataGrid.SelectedItem).Row["PersonID"].ToString();

        SelectedPersonID = Int32.Parse(ID);

        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new PersonProfile());
    }
```

Is there a better way to open the PersonProfile Page? Is there an easy way to open the Page using single click on a row?

Thanks.

Comment: I removed the MouseDoubleClick="PersonDataGrid_CellClicked" in XAML and replaced it with DataGridCell.Selected="PersonDataGrid_CellClicked"   I can now single click to open the Page. BUT, the sender object is the DataGridItems.Count and now the program throws the error on     this.NavigationService.Navigate(new PersonProfile());

Comment: Used Joseph's example to get this working. Thanks to both posters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A better way to do it, is to define a collection of `Person` that define the `DataGrid` `ItemSource` and a Property of type `Person` that contains the selected Item in the `DataGrid`:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="PersonDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit ="FullRow"       
            MouseRightButtonUp="PersonDataGrid_CellClicked" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PersonId}" Header="Id"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=PersonName}" Header="Name"  />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

and the `SelectedPerson` and `Persons` are defined in the code behind of this page like so :

```
 public partial class Page1 : Page,INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Person> _persons ;
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons
    {
        get
        {
            return _persons;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_persons == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _persons = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private Person _selectedPerson ;
    public Person SelectedPerson
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPerson;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_selectedPerson == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _selectedPerson = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
public class Person
{
   public int PersonId { get; set; }
   public string PersonName { get; set; }
}
```

the `INotifyPropertyChanged` is used to notify the UI of any changes in the Properties.
You could use the `SelectedPerson` Property or pass it to the new page, when you receive the `MouseRightButtonUp` event for example in the `DataGrid`:

```
    private void PersonDataGrid_CellClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedPerson == null)
            return;
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(new PersonProfile(SelectedPerson));
    }
```

and you could change the `PersonProfile` Page to receive a Person in its Constructor.

Comment: I am currently filling the DataGrid using a DataSet filled by a SQL query. So should I be using the query to fill a Person class instead?

Comment: Yes, use the query result to fill the Persons Collection

Comment: Thanks. This does give the single click result. I changed MouseRightButtonUp to MouseLeftButtonUp in your example to use single left button click. Now to try to learn MVVM!.

Answer (score 0):

The exception you are getting is because the SelectedItem is sometimes null. To make sure you are getting the value you want use the sender object and cast it to the proper type. As for a better way I would look into the MVVM pattern. It would involve binding the SelectedItem to an object. This might be a little much because you are new but it's what I recommend.

Comment: That's part of what I'm not understanding. Each row has an entry for PersonID and the error only occurs sometimes. Other times it works fine.    Could you also elaborate on the suggested binding? thanks.

Comment: I cast the sender and found when the error occurs the sender is an Item count of the datagrid. I removed the MouseDoubleClick="PersonDataGrid_CellClicked"  in XAML and haven't had the error since.